# S3 Put Event FilterRule for file name (prefix)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet

I would like to trigger a lambda when a new parquet file lands in a particular path in S3.

The files that will land in that path will look like this:

Example_1.parquet
Example_2.parquet
Example_3.parquet

In my “FilterRules” I will define “.parquet” as the Suffix, but I would ONLY like this lambda triggered when Example_1.parquet lands in S3.

Is there any way I can create a filter rule that will only trigger my lambda function when a file name contains “_1” ??

Keeping in mind “_1” might occur elsewhere in the file name… but I would only like it to detect at the END of the file name before the suffix.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason just specifying the suffix of `_1.parquet` wouldn't match this criteria?